# How can to remove the default active background color in ReactNative Material Bottom Tabs version 6.2.10

Tags: react-native, material-ui, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v6

please I Will like to learn how to remove this background color in the image below. I've tried all props in the documentation, nothing worked.

[image: The background color is the one the arrow is pointing too. I think it's a new problem with the latest release.]

Answer (score 1):

```
npm or yarn add react-native-paper
```

```js
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';

const theme = useTheme();

theme.colors.secondaryContainer = "transperent" //or color of your choice
```

should get rid of the default background color

Answer (score 0):

Add TabBarOptions in Tab.navigator like below

```js
 <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent', 
          showIcon: true,
          showLabel: false,
        }}
      >
```